Verifying Trigonometric Identities given $x$ value.
Verify $$\sin^2(x)-\cos^2(x)-\tan^2(x)=\frac{2\sin(x)-2\sin^4(x)-1}{1-\sin^2(x)}$$ for $x=45^{\circ}$. The value for the LHS was solved for -1. The RHS however I was unable to solve for using a calculator. The LHS can be simplified into $$-\frac{\cos^2(x)\cos(2x)+\sin(x)^2}{\cos(x)^2}.$$
The RHS I was only able to simplify to $$\frac{2\sin(x)-2\sin^4(x)-1}{\cos^2(x)}.$$ When checking the equality of the LHS to the RHS I get 2 different values. I believe the numerator of the RHS may be able to be simplified by using the MacLaurin series, I know there is a way to do this without using it though. Perhaps both sides may need to be/are able to be simplified further in order to verify for $x=45^{\circ}$. The calculator I am using does seem to be able to process $\sin^4(x)$, which can be expressed in expanded cosine form as $1-2\cos^2(x)+\cos^4(x)$. Surely I am missing something here, hopefully someone can help me piece everything together.

Is just ... plugging in $x=45^\circ$ not allowed?

If the instructions are to "verify" the relation, then you shouldn't have to bother simplifying the expressions trigonometrically. Just substitute $x=45^\circ$ and see what happens arithmetically. The value of $\tan(x)$ is particularly nice. $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are a bit less so, but they're equal; and, conveniently, they're almost-always raised to an even power. ... Actually, the fact that there's a non-squared sine is problematic, as it makes the RHS irrational while the LHS is rational, so the relation as written is invalid. (Squaring that un-squared sine makes things work.)

There's a typographical error in the RHS. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870527/prove-this-trig-identity

Why are you using a calculator? $\sin45^{\circ}=\cos45^{\circ}=(1/2)\sqrt2$ (and $(\sqrt2)^2=2$) is all you need to know to evaluate both sides.
